# Is there a way to do JSON Conversions in spring boot, similar to MuleSoft Dataweave Operations?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, gson, mule, spring-restcontroller

I am interested to do any complex JSON to JSON(Anything) or JSON to Flat file transformations, like done in MuleSoft(using operators like map, filter, pluck, orderBy, groupBy, etc.) but in spring boot using Java. It's know to me that MuleSoft is a spring based Middleware. But, I couldn't find to see such complex Mulesoft functionalities & offerings done implemented in java separately. Could someone provide me a Mule JSON map operator & else more ; equivalent example code in Spring Boot ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for but I forgot to add it here. It is possible to call Dataweave from Spring boot app using Java. Here is the an example

[DW Transformers](https://github.com/omkarium/dw-transformers)

Answer (score 2):

Applies for JSON to JSON transforms:

Try using Jolt, not exactly as powerful as Mulesoft Dataweave but can help you do quite a lot of JSON to JSON transformations

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a very useful Repo to achieve the problem statement, especially in Java. I have found some good tutorial sites on this implementation. https://www.hascode.com/2017/01/transforming-and-reducing-json-structures-with-jolt/

Answer (score 2):

I found [Datasonnet](https://datasonnet.com/) online when researching your answer. Looks like an open source alternative to Dataweave, which allows complex transformations like those you listed.

Comment: Thanks ! I need to check this. Feels like this works with JS syntax. Can this be implemented in spring boot platform ? Have you implemented such ?

Comment: No I haven't tried working with it yet. It's in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:datasonnet-mapper), and there is a [library for it in camel](https://github.com/modusbox/datasonnet-mapper), so I imagine it is compatible with spring boot.